# How to specify the MainClass for java

Tags: java, compilation

I am trying to make a `.bat` the script just for running a java file where I try to use the JNI, but I have an interesting problem.

The directory where the script should be is called `NativeMethodTest` and contains a folder called `out`
 
Now when I am in the `out` folder I can call my main class just with

`java HelloWorld`
and it just works fine, but when i am in the parent folder it seems to start runnig with the command 
`java -cp "./out" HelloWorld` 
but i get this Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no hello in java.library.path
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at HelloWorld.<clinit>(HelloWorld.java:8)
```

but the HelloWorld.java contains this line
`System.setProperty("java.library.path", "D:\\projects\\NativeMethodTest\\out\\.");`

which sets my library path absolute, so it should work and it does when I am in the same folder, but not in the parent, please help
**thanks**

here the folder structure:

`./NativeMethodTest/run.bat
 ./NativeMethodTest/out/hello.dll
 ./NativeMethodTest/out/HelloWorld.class`

Comment: You can't specify (or modify) the java.library.path from within Java.

Answer (score 0):

ok, this is weird since the `getProperty("java.library.path")`method gives the path, so i made a false assumption, but thanks to Elliott i fixed my script to 
`java -cp "./out" -Djava.library.path=".\out\."  HelloWorld` 
which now works fine from the parent too, 
thank you have a nice day